# VS Code doesn't show right source on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I'm trying to set up VS Code for Javascript debugging. My code is written in ECMASCRIPT 2018 and needs to be transpiled with babel.

When I place a breakpoint on a line of source and launch the debugger, VS Code breaks properly, but shows me the transpiled code instead. Here is my launch configuration:

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "SQS Sync",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/sqs.js",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/lib/**.js"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "protocol": "inspector"
    }
```

`npm: build` is a task that runs babel with `--source-maps`. It takes all the files in `src/` and transpiles to to `lib/`. The source maps are created properly (obviously, otherwise VS Code wouldn't have known where to stop).